# Protractor Looping Not Able to Click Correct Item

Tags: javascript, protractor

Looping through and trying to print out to the console my choice and clicking is not working properly. Each of my list items have text and the list item itself is clickable. I'm trying to iterate through the list to match text (choice_item), if it matches it prints to console and clicks that item.

But when I check my output, it clicks the next item after it.
For example, it will print:

Item 1

Item 2

choice found: Item 2

Item 3

And then clicks Item 3 instead of Item 2 (The choice_item that I want to find in the list). Any explanation on how to fix this and/or control flow mistakes I am making will be greatly appreciated!

```
this.getListItems = function(choice_item){
    var choice = "";
    this.getSelectionsList().filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.element(by.css('.choicename')).getText().then(function(text) {
            if(text === choice_item){
                console.log("choice found:"+ choice_item);
                choice = text;
                elem.click();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }).then(function(items) {
        expect(choice).toBe(choice_item);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter the element by the `choice_item` text and click it:

```
this.getListItems = function(choice_item) {
    var listItems = this.getSelectionsList().filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.element(by.css('.choicename')).getText().then(function(text) {
            return text === choice_item;
        });
    });

    listItems.first().click();
};
```

Note that there is no need to `expect()` here since you are already applying the `choice_item` check while filtering the list item.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a control flow mistake.
Try this way:

```
this.getListItems = function(choice_item){
    var choice = "";
    this.getSelectionsList().filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.element(by.css('.choicename')).getText(); //it returns promise

    }).then(function(text) {
        //getText() Promise fulfill
        if(text === choice_item){
            console.log("choice found:"+ choice_item);
            choice = text;
            elem.click();
            browser.sleep(2000);
            expect(choice).toBe(choice_item);
        }

    });
};
```

The best way for click methods. Do factory function, for example:

```
var click1 = function (element){
    element.click();
    return new Promise (function (fulfill, reject){
      setTimeout(function(){
      fulfill();
      },2000);
    }    
});
```

And You can use this:

```
click1(elem).then(function (){
 //the code
});
```

But in your code the `click()` event influence nothing, because the `getText()` is earlier than `click()`.